# My loop prints multiple times. How do I get it to print once?

Tags: c

I'm writing a code where if a name that is entered does not match the names in a list, it prints "Dog not found." If not, it prints the list.

My problem is it prints "Dog not found" multiple times, instead of just one time.

Code:

```
void search (struct dog *list)
{
   char name[NAME_LEN+1];

   struct dog *p;

   printf("Enter dog’s name: \n");
   scanf("%s", name);

   name[0] = toupper(name[0]);
   for(p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next)
   {
      if(strcmp(name, p->dog_name) != 0)
      {
         printf("Dog not found.");
      }
      else
      {
          printf("\n");
          printf("%d \t",p->number);
          printf("%s \t",p->dog_name);
          printf("%s \t",p->breed);
          printf("%s \t",p->owner_last_name);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your `scarf` statement is subject to buffer overflow if the user enters a name longer than `NAME_LEN` characters long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't print the not found message until the search is complete.

The below example assumes that only one dog in the list will match. So the loop is terminated as soon as one if found. If multiple matches are possible then don't `break` immediately but set a `found` flag instead and keep searching.

```
for(p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next)
{
  if(strcmp(name, p->dog_name) == 0)
      printf("\n");
      printf("%d \t",p->number);
      printf("%s \t",p->dog_name);
      printf("%s \t",p->breed);
      printf("%s \t",p->owner_last_name);
      break;
  }
}

if (p == NULL) { 
    printf("Dog not found.");
}
```

As an extra note, `name[0] = toupper(name[0]);` is not really the right way to normalise the input. For example, if the user enters an unexpected upper case letter in the middle of the name then your search will fail. Instead should either make the entire string upper/lower case or use a non-case sensitive compare (e.g `strcasecmp` on POSIX systems).

Comment: How do I add a found flag? I changed my code, and it worked, the only thing is that it shows "Dog not found" at the end after printing the list.

Comment: Please show exactly what your updated code looks like.